# Jenkins error while authenticating subversion

Tags: linux, tomcat, svn, jenkins

I have upgraded my Kernel to Patch 3 and after that I am unable to connect to Subversion from Jenkins.My Jenkins is running in apache tomcat server.

```
INFO: Failed to access subversion repository https://SVNREPO/TestPMD
Throwable occurred: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /TestPMD failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:379)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:364)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:352)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.performHttpRequest(DAVConnection.java:708)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.exchangeCapabilities(DAVConnection.java:628)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVConnection.open(DAVConnection.java:103)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.openConnection(DAVRepository.java:1018)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.DAVRepository.testConnection(DAVRepository.java:99)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.checkRepositoryPath(SubversionSCM.java:2038)
    at hudson.scm.SubversionSCM$DescriptorImpl.doCheckRemote(SubversionSCM.java:1972)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function$InstanceFunction.invoke(Function.java:297)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvoke(Function.java:160)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Function.bindAndInvokeAndServeResponse(Function.java:95)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$1.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:111)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:685)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:799)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:239)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:685)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:799)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.MetaClass$6.doDispatch(MetaClass.java:239)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.NameBasedDispatcher.dispatch(NameBasedDispatcher.java:53)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.tryInvoke(Stapler.java:685)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:799)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.invoke(Stapler.java:587)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.Stapler.service(Stapler.java:218)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:723)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:290)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter$1.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:96)
    at hudson.util.PluginServletFilter.doFilter(PluginServletFilter.java:88)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at hudson.security.csrf.CrumbFilter.doFilter(CrumbFilter.java:48)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter$1.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:84)
    at hudson.security.ChainedServletFilter.doFilter(ChainedServletFilter.java:76)
    at hudson.security.HudsonFilter.doFilter(HudsonFilter.java:164)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.kohsuke.stapler.compression.CompressionFilter.doFilter(CompressionFilter.java:46)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at hudson.util.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilter(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:81)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:235)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:206)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:233)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:191)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:470)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:127)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:109)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:293)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:861)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:606)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:489)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS /TestPMD failed
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:154)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:97)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNException: svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/TestPMD'
svn: E175002: SSLv3 SSLContext not available
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:64)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.wc.SVNErrorManager.error(SVNErrorManager.java:51)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:754)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.request(HTTPConnection.java:373)
    ... 62 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: OPTIONS request failed on '/TestPMD'
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:208)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:752)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: svn: E175002: SSLv3 SSLContext not available
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.SVNErrorMessage.create(SVNErrorMessage.java:109)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:507)
    ... 63 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SSLv3 SSLContext not available
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createSSLContext(SVNSocketFactory.java:235)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.util.SVNSocketFactory.createSSLSocket(SVNSocketFactory.java:79)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection.connect(HTTPConnection.java:270)
    at org.tmatesoft.svn.core.internal.io.dav.http.HTTPConnection._request(HTTPConnection.java:435)
    ... 63 more
```

Comment: try disabling sslv3 from java control panel

Comment: I am using Linux, how to do disable sslv3 here?

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3
```

in your httpd.conf for all your virtualhost and restart. This should work

Comment: In apache tomcat, I can't see httpd.conf file.Can you please let me know where this file will be?

Comment: ps -ef | grep apache will give you the process with directory, go to that directory and -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE

Comment: I only got apache-tomcat directory..and what is that -V | grep SERVER_CONFIG_FILE

Comment: Moreover, in apache tomcat we don't have httpd.conf I guess

Comment: shikjohari -can you please advise?